# Cannot get IIS 8 to properly authenticate to SQL Server 2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, sql-server-2012, iis-8

I am running IIS 8 on a Windows 8.1 home premium machine. I'm trying to publish for my home network an MVC application that logs in to SQL Server (2012 Developer Edition) on the same machine.The SQL Server is set up to use Windows Authentication.

The published (to the local file system) MVC application works fine when used from Visual Studio 2013. When ran via IIS, it connects to the home page, but crashes the moment data is accessed with the message "Login failed for user 'WORKGROUP[my home machine]"

Can I get there from here? After research, I see that I **cannot set** the Authentication for IIS to Windows Authentication for a Home Premium machine (option is not there, only Anonymous, ASP.NET Impersonation and Forms Authentication are there and I could make none work). So what should I do? Change authentication on SQL Server? It should be so easy--both Web and Sql Servers are on the same machine! Any/all ideas very welcome!

Comment: Change to SQL Server authentication (user name plus password) should be your best option. Another is to change application pool identity to a local user account that has access to SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

Well, first off, there's no such thing as Windows 8 or Windows 8.1 Home Premium.  There is only Windows 8.1 and Windows 8.1 Pro.  The Home and Home Premium version names were dropped after Windows 7.  Additionally, the IIS in Windows 8 does not have the same limitations that were present in earlier versions of IIS, although you still can't connect to a domain.  You need 8.x Pro for that.

So, your problem here is that, by default, IIS uses the computer name (including Workgroup or Domain) to login to Sql Server when using Windows Authentication and Integrated security.  All you have to do is add your computer to the authorized users for the database.

Simply go into SQL Server Management Studio, open up the server, go to Security->Logins and add the machine, then go to the database and add the newly created machine account to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Ok , you need just add Authencitcated user ( if both IIS and sql server are on same Computer ) , ( NetworkService if they aren't on same Computer ) to database login .